# Rails 6 How to resolve ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in public/packs/manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am following a simple tutorial on how to use MongoDB with rails. It is a traditionally simple blog app where you have all CRUD actions. The tutorial can be found here.

[MongoDB with Rails](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/getting-started-rails/#new-application)

I am trying to set up a fresh Rails 6 application but am running into a series of problems with web packer. To begin with, when I try to access `localhost:3000/posts`, I receive the following error:

> Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Posts#index

The error has the following recomendations

```
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

I currently do not have a `manifest.json` file. When I try to run `bundle exec rake webpacker:compile`, I get the following error:

```
Compilation failed:
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.node should be one of these:
   false | object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff.
   Details:
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'dgram'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'net'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'tls'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'child_process'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
```

From these errors and reading some stack overflow questions, I am having a very difficult time getting this simple application to load and I'm not sure how to attack the problem.

For starters, I have the latest node installed which is `node v14.15.0`. Secondly, I should have all the dependencies needed to run the js portion of the app. Here is my `package.json`.

```
{
"name": "blog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to go about fixing this problem. I've already done what some stack overflow questions have suggested. I have reinstalled yarn, updated node, etc. I could really use some help as to how to get past this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I made the same mistake, but maybe the webpacker and Manifest, which aren't compatible with the latest version, interfered because I put in the latest version of webpack / webpack cli myself? This is a package.json I started with Rails6 + vue.js but I don't have webpack / webpack cli installed. You can still start it.

```
package.json

{
  "name": "app_name",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "postcss-selector-parser": "^6.0.4",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss-multi-column": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify on this comment, I was facing the same error and removed `"webpack"` from the dependencies list and two copies of `"webpack-cli"` from the dev dependencies. After that, `webpacker:compile` worked and the error went away on the next launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the existing webpack and try these steps.

```
yarn add webpack@4

yarn add webpack-cli

yarn add @rails/webpacker

yarn add bootstrap@next jquery @popperjs/core
```

Check if the webpack is compiling well

```
bin/rails webpacker:compile
```